# PercentileAggregation - Convert into HashMap

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

I am using `PercentileAggregation` in my code.
Results from _plugin/head:

```
"aggregations": {
"load_time_outlier": {
"values": {
"1.0": 35,
"1.0_as_string": "35.0",
"5.0": 35,
"5.0_as_string": "35.0",
"25.0": 35,
"25.0_as_string": "35.0",
"50.0": 35,
"50.0_as_string": "35.0",
"75.0": 35,
"75.0_as_string": "35.0",
"95.0": 36,
"95.0_as_string": "36.0",
"99.0": 36,
"99.0_as_string": "36.0"
}
}
}
```

through the Java client( TCP), I am getting it as `InternalPercentiles`.

```
    Aggregations aggregations = response.getAggregations();
    if(aggregations.getAsMap().get(aggregationKey) instanceof InternalPercentiles){
    InternalPercentiles intPercentiles = 
      (InternalPercentiles) aggregations.getAsMap().get(aggregationKey);
//My logic here
}
```

I want to write a logic in commented place, so that I would get my result as a map: 
**Key:**    load_time_outlier
**value:**  list containing a Map of [{"1.0": 35}, { "5.0": 35},etc..]

Logic I tried:

```
Iterator<Percentile> iterator = intPercentiles.iterator();
Map<String, Object> aggregationTermsMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
while(iterator.hasNext()){
    Percentile percentile = iterator.next();
    aggregationTermsMap.put(new Double(percentile.getPercent()).toString(), percentile.getValue());
}
aggregationTermsList.add(aggregationTermsMap);
aggregationResults.put(aggregationKey, aggregationTermsList);
```

inputs please.

Comment: What does the tried logic give you right now?

Comment: I am getting percentile object as empty. Just resolved it by adding class cast. Iterator<Percentile> iterator = ((InternalPercentiles)intPercentiles).iterator();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got an answer: Class cast ((InternalPercentiles)intPercentiles).iterator() was missing.

```
Iterator<Percentile> iterator = ((InternalPercentiles)intPercentiles).iterator();
Map<String, Object> aggregationTermsMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
while(iterator.hasNext()){
    Percentile percentile = iterator.next();
    aggregationTermsMap.put(new Double(percentile.getPercent()).toString(), percentile.getValue());
}
aggregationTermsList.add(aggregationTermsMap);
aggregationResults.put(aggregationKey, aggregationTermsList);
```